# Getting following error while installing npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm, js2coffee

I am getting following error while running `npm install`. I am not sure how to fix it. I am using npm version 2.*.

```
-
js2coffee@0.2.7 preinstall C:\workspace\cct-ui-mylocal\client\node_modules\gru
npm run-script ./cyclic.js

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! missing script: ./cyclic.js
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\workspace\cct-ui-mylocal\client\node_modules\grunt-ng-constant\n
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! js2coffee@0.2.7 preinstall: `npm run-script ./cyclic.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the js2coffee@0.2.7 preinstall script 'npm run-script ./cycli
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the js2coffee package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run-script ./cyclic.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls js2coffee
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\workspace\cct-ui-mylocal\client\npm-debug.log */
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use npm v1 or update the package in question.